# Identity server 4 access token with custom lifetime

Tags: access-token, identityserver4

I have a scenario where I have to return custom access token to a user who has not validated his/her email. Access token has to expire after 24 hours regardless of access token lifetime specified for a client.

Is there a way to specify lifetime of access token per quest. I already have "**IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator**" interface implemented.

One option I came across is to to use Identity server tools "IdentityServerTools"
to generate a token but don't know how to return proper token response with refresh token(which still needs to be generated).

```
var token = await _identityServerTools.IssueClientJwtAsync(
                clientId: context.Request.Client.ClientId,
                lifetime: 86400, // 24 hours in seconds
                scopes: context.Request.Scopes
            );
```

Comment: This issue is similar your scenario, might be helpful for you https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2112

Comment: @ademcaglin I came across this github issue but it doesn't provide much help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is not tested but it could be a solution:

```
internal class YourCustomTokenRequestValidator : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
{
    // your email checker which takes an `IClaimsPrincipal` parameter
    private readonly IEmailChecker emailChecker;
    public YourCustomTokenRequestValidator(IEmailChecker emailChecker)
    {
        this.emailChecker = emailChecker;
    }
    public Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
    {
        var request = context.Result.ValidatedRequest;
        var isVerified = false;
        var subject = request.Subject ?? request.AuthorizationCode?.Subject;
        if(subject != null)
        {
           isVerified = emailChecker.IsVerified(subject);
           if (!isVerified)
           {
              request.AccessTokenLifetime = 24 * 60 * 60;
           }
        } 

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Register custom implementation:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
           .AddCustomTokenRequestValidator<YourCustomTokenRequestValidator>()
            /// ;
```

Comment: what namespace contains this extension method? AddCustomTokenRequestValidator

Comment: @GabrielMartinezBustos  Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection